# UnsupportedClassVersionError use SwipeListView

Tags: android, eclipse, unsupported-class-version

I use SwipeListView in my android layout,

it shows UnsupportedClassVersionError, change to ListView it's OK.

I tried install JRE 6 in eclipse(at first it's JRE 7 with eclipse 4.4.1, install separately),

it's still same problem. What's the problem might be?

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.example.dissstool.widgets.SwipeListView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: android/support/v4/view/ViewConfigurationCompat : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(ClassLoader.java:-2)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:-2)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectClassLoader.loadClassFromJar(ProjectClassLoader.java:281)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:80)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.example.dissstool.widgets.SwipeListView.init(SwipeListView.java:219)
    at com.example.dissstool.widgets.SwipeListView.<init>(SwipeListView.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:442)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:194)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:206)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:131)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:756)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:728)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is eclipse Luna(4.4.1) not support jdk 1.6, the basic require is jdk 1.7. I remove eclipse 4.4.1 and install the eclipse Kepler (4.3.2), it works.